# What must be the capacity of the tank?

Tags: probability

[image]

Here is my work:

[image]

[image]

**I'm not sure that it is correct, I'm thinking that the 0.01 LHS is wrong. 
The LHS, could be 1-0.01=0.99 because of the curve? I'm not sure of which one is correct. I need help to clarify this concept. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK. Just that $P(X\leq c)$ should read $P(X\geq c)$.

As a quick check, now that you have 
$$P(X\geq c)=(1-c)^5$$
put $$\begin{cases}c=0\\c=1\end{cases}$$  respectively to confirm that 
$$\begin{cases}P(X\geq 0)=1\\P(X\geq 1)=0\end{cases}$$
as would be expected.

Comment: But I can't see why my TA. said that  I should calculate P(x > capacity) = 0.01, which implies that P(x < capacity) = 0.99 and so we want to x such that F(x) = 0.99.  Therefore, if that's is true my mistake is in the symbol that you said no?? And the value of c will not be 0.6 again , no? Thanks again.

Comment: You want demand (X)<capacity (c) 99% of the time. Value of $c$ is correct, as you are integrating the pdf from $c$ to $1$ and not from $0$ to $c$.